# How to know when angular has finished deferring

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am struggling to understand Angular deffering and promises.
I would like to know when all promises have been completed so i can hide a "loading" message.
So here is my code example:

```
$scope.buildTeam = function () {
    $scope.Message = "loading...";

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promiseList = [];

    c = $scope.teamModels[0];

    for (index = 0; index < c.quantity; ++index) {
            var assignment = new teamAssignment(c.assignmentTypeId, $scope.parentAssignment.AssignmentId, c.description);
            promiseList.push(departmentService.addAssignment(assignment).then(function (result) {

                //added lead/captain. Now insert visually on page
                insertToScope($scope, result);

            }));
        }

    } 

    $q.all(promiseList).then(function () {
        deferred.resolve();
        $scope.Message = "Loaded.";
    });
}
```

The problem is Have is that $scope.Message shows "Loaded" well before the data has been inserted onto the page in the case of a large data pull.
Could it be that i also need to defer insertToScope?
InsertToScope simply reads:

```
function insertToScope($scope, a) {
   //get root scope
   var rs = angular.element("#ngRootContainer").scope();
   rs.parentAssig.push(a);
}
```

And the department service looks like this:

```
departmentModule.factory('departmentService', function ($http, $q) {
return {
    addAssignment: function(assignment){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post('/Department/addAssignmentReturnAssignmentRow', assignment).success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
});
```

So my question is, what do i need to do to call a function only after all the promises are done?
Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: As far as I can tell you're on the right track, what does departmentService.addAssignment look like?

Comment: hi brianj -  good pickup, i added it to the end of the question. thank you.

Comment: As long as `insertToScope` finishes in the same digest loop, there shouldn't be a problem. Please create a Plunkr that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: FYI, you're creating many promises that are not needed. `$http.post` returns a promise, so you can just return that. `$q.all` returns a promise so you don't need the `deferred` variable.

Comment: @PieterHerroelen is correct, what you're doing is called the deferred anti pattern.

Comment: Hi Pieter, when say inserting 20 items in a loop, the http promise would return done on the first item. Hence why i assumed i had to nest  all those inside another promise to know when all 20 (for example) were done. I will build a plunkr example as I would love to figure out how to best approach this. Are you suggesting that i get rid of the deffered var, and simply just call q.all(promiselist).then(function(){sucess is here})?
Thanks guys.

Comment: Hi @PieterHerroelen, just a ping as i forgot to add the @ before your name so you would see my previous response. Would love your feedback on the comment! Even happy for a link showing many deffered. Not much on SO on this. Txs.

Comment: I got my above example from [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084271/how-to-know-when-a-long-series-of-async-calls-is-finished-in-angularjs?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$q.all` should do what you need. If your code doesn't work, I see two options:

- You pass in a `promiseList` that does not contain all promises you want to wait for. Debug your code and check that all promises are passed in. Make sure it's an array you pass as the first parameter.
- The promises you pass in resolve before you expect them to resolve. If you log 'A' in `insertToScope`, and 'B' in the `then` of your `$q.all`, you should see

> ```
> A
> ...
> A
> B
> ```

in the console.

Here is a simple plunkr that shows how to use `$q.all()`: http://plnkr.co/edit/9QH9Y0w7DG0WCouMuX82?p=preview

Comment: Hi @PieterHerroelen, thank you so much. That plunkr is so simple, and easy to understand, i finally "got it" on first glance.